# Update fragment on all activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I created a fragment which is basically a counter. When pressed, it updates the number of water glasses you've drunk. This data is stored in SharedPreferences. I also update this number once a day as well.
So i inserted fragment in xml of two activities: Main and the Timer.
It's perfectly work on the Main, when i  start the TimerActivity it's also work, but when i go back to Main from Timer i see the last number i've reached in MainActivity, it's not updating and ignore my clicks from TimerActivity.
I think the trouble in "this.getActivity", but i don't know how to fix it. Thanks

**Fragment code**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.fitapp.R;

import java.util.Calendar;
public class WaterBottleFragment extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout waterBottle;
    TextView iconName;

    SharedPreferences sPref;
    int counter;
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_water_bottle, container, false);

        // Update once a day
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        sPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("startApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int lastDay = sPref.getInt("day", 0);
        if(lastDay != currentDay){
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
            ed.putInt("day", currentDay);
            ed.commit();
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            counter = (int) loadText();
        }

        waterBottle = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_water_bottle);
        iconName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_icon_water);

        
        iconName.setText(counter + " glasses");
        waterBottle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                iconName.setText(counter + " glasses");
                saveText();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // Save number of glasses
    private void saveText() {
        sPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("water_counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putInt("num_of_glasses", counter);
        ed.commit();
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Load number of glasses
    private int loadText() {
        sPref = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("water_counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedCounter = sPref.getInt("num_of_glasses", 2);
        return savedCounter;
    }
}
```

Comment: consider posting some test cases or additional classes needed to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

its not a big deal just create an interface like:

```
Public interface WaterBottleEventListener{
void onBottleClick();
}
```

create an object of your interface inside your fragment:

```
WaterBottleEventListener listener;
```

Then call it inside your waterBottle.setonclicklistener:

```
waterBottle.setonclicklistener(){
@override
onclick(View v){
listener.onbottleclick();
}
}
```

Then make both of your activities implement this interface and inside each implementation put your update glass code like this:

```
Activity1 implement waterBottleEventListener{


@override
onBottleclick(){
counter++;
IconName.setText(...)
...

}


}
```

Comment: iconName and methods like saveText or loadText are in Fragment class, should i use FragmentManager to manage the iconName and put my methods in both of Activities?
And also for counter, it's defined in Fragment, how can i get access to this variable?